# Custom action getting published multiple times on user's timeline for same object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I just noticed that when I publish an action on the user's timeline for the same object multiple times, using facebook's 'built-in' action type (eg: 'read' an article), i get an error response, something like "action is already associated to the user on this object". But when i try to do the same for a custom action that i created(eg: 'agreed' with an article), I don't get any error message, instead the actions gets published multiple times. I want my custom action to behave just like facebook's default action-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the action type settings, in app's settings, you have an option called `Unique Action`.

Unique Action has the following options to choose from:

- `Allow Multiple`
- `Allow Only Once`

Choose `Allow Only Once`, and it would act like facebook `read` action - only once per object.